# How to use Application.Intersect Method

Tags: vba, excel

Good evening to everyone,

as the title suggests, I have a problem with the Application.Intersect method  in excel vba.

This is my situation:

[image: I have 3 columns (A1:A7 , B1:B7 , C1:C7). My aim is take the values contained in A18:B18 , D18:E18 , G18:I18 one by one, and check if each of them is contained in each of the 3 columns described above]

Example: is A18 conteined in A1:A7? is B18 conteined in A1:A7? .... Is I18 conteined in A1:A7? Write the result and then move on to the next column.

To do this, I wrote the following code:

```
Sub Macro1() 
Dim column As Range
Dim val As Range
Dim table As Range
Set table = Range("A1:C7")
Dim result As Range
Set result = Range("A9:C9")
Dim b As Integer
b = 0
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim control1 As Range
Set control1 = Range("A18")
Dim control2 As Range
Set control2 = Range("B18")
Dim control3 As Range
Set control3 = Range("D18")
Dim control4 As Range
Set control4 = Range("E18")
Dim control5 As Range
Set control5 = Range("G18")
Dim control6 As Range
Set control6 = Range("H18")
Dim control7 As Range
Set control7 = Range("I18")
For Each column In table.Columns
    Set isect1 = Application.Intersect(control1, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect1 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect2 = Application.Intersect(control2, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect2 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect3 = Application.Intersect(control3, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect3 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect4 = Application.Intersect(control4, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect4 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect5 = Application.Intersect(control5, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect5 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect6 = Application.Intersect(control6, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect6 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect7 = Application.Intersect(control7, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect7 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Set isect8 = Application.Intersect(control8, table.Columns(i).val)
        If (Not (isect8 Is Nothing)) Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
        If b = 8 Then
            result(i).val= "ok"
        Else
            result(i).val= "no"
        End If
Next column
End Sub
```

The problems are:

- the Application.Intersect method return Always the same result there
- is probably a simpler way to do this, but I could not find it
- every time I set isect gives me an error: "necessary object"

Thank you all for your help!

EDIT: I tried to change `Set isect1 = Application.Intersect(control1, table.Columns(i).val)` with `Set isect1 = Application.Intersect(control1, table.Columns(i))`  but so it is always not intersected

EDIT2: Resolved thanks to the help of TimWilliams!

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Intersect is expecting two ranges, the second argument is `table.Columns(i).val`, which is a property that I don't think exists. Try `Application.Intersect(control1,table.Columns(i).EntireColumn).Value`

Comment: @SJR I have 3 columns (A1:A7 , B1:B7 , C1:C7). My aim is take the values contained in A18:B18 , D18:E18 , G18:I18 one by one, and check if each of them is contained in each of the 3 columns described above.

Comment: Please can you add that to your question. @BrownishMonster has identified a problem. Why don't you just use COUNTIF or MATCH?

Comment: @BrownishMonster  I tried to do as you suggested, but I have a new error: "property or method not supported by the object"

Comment: You should use countif - Intersect is for Range objects, not for the values contained in the ranges)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you very much for helping! I finally solved my problem!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a COUNTIF method for this:

```
Dim sht, col, c, v

Set sht = ActiveSheet
For Each col In sht.Range("A1:C7").Columns
For Each c In sht.Range("A18:H18").Cells
    v = Application.CountIf(col, c)
    Debug.Print c.Value & IIf(v > 0, " is ", " is not ") & _
           "contained in " & col.Address()
Next c
Next col
```